# Using DAOs with composite Objects

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

I am trying to rewrite a bunch of DAOs here is the setting:

- only plain JDBC (no JPA, ORM whatsoever)
- no interfaces used
- lots of checks before inserting an object
- Business objects are strongly linked

My main question is:
How do I persist/retrieve a business object that is composed of multiple other objects?
e.g. does my CustomerDAO know the AddressDAO and retrieve the csutomers adresses from there?

Comment: take a look at [jcabi-jdbc](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc), it's a lightweight wrapper around JDBC (I'm a developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> only plain JDBC (no JPA, ORM whatsoever)
>   Business objects are strongly linked

Not sure why you don't want to use JPA while you want your business objects to be linked, but at least you should use Spring JDBC template that would relieve you from some boilerplate code.

Regarding the other constraints, I would do it as follows:

1. I would still employ interfaces to define the `DAO` methods and implement them in a Spring JDBC template backed `DAOImpl`. Use the DAO everywhere and inject the DAOImpl.
2. My DAOs will be simply one-to-one mapping to the underlying tables and each DAO wouldn't know about the existence of other DAOs.
3. My Manager layer will have all the business logic that runs validation checks and prepares the set of objects that need to be persisted, calls the appropriate DAO and appropriate method (CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE) to persist the objects.
4. Again, the Manager layer will follow the interface-based implementation and the view layer would have manager types injected with the ManagerImpls.

My two cents!

Comment: Thanks! I thought about JPA. So far the counter argument was that this application is in no way solidly engineered and I am not sure how bolting on JPA would work. (This thing does not even run in an application server!). However if I get you right points 2-4 would essentially mean I code my own entityManager, right?

Comment: That's right, your manager layer will be knowledgeable about the associations among different domain objects (e.g. Customer, Address) etc., If you used JPA specification to define your entities and their associations and employed a JPA provider (like Hibernate), they would have taken care of persisting the object hierarchy and your could would concentrate on the data-transfer-object -> domain object translation.

Answer (score 0):

You may Consider Using [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). It is not JPA, but it may easily be used as an alternative solution. It is lightweight enough. It also provides provides a reverse engineer tool, where it builds your Database entities as DAO objects.

I have embed JOOQ in a relevant situation, where the application was fairly engineered designed. I didn't use its DAO functionality, rather than using it as a higher layer to avoid messing with JDBC Layer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Composite entities are a layer above DAO's. If you want to remove ALL coupling, domain objects persisted by DAOs should be flat without relationships. See Core J2EE patterns CompositeEntity.

Also, it's a good idea not to introduce coupling inbetween the DAO's by putting finders for one in the other. E.g.:

AddressDAO.findForCustomerId(id);

is inferior to using a third DAO to manage the relationship. I.E:

CustomerAddressRelDAO.findAddressForCustomer(id);

If you use a relationship DAO neither address nor customer are dependent on (or aware of) each other.